# form submit doesn't work in php

Tags: php, jquery

This file is the return file using ajax to sorting a table when checkbox is checked, 
But the submit button doesn't work in following coding, 
When seems there is nothing wrong in this code as per my knowledge

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){
        alert("Submitted");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th class="heading"> 
        Sl No.
        </th>
        <th class="heading"> 
        Order Id
        </th>
        <th class="heading"> 
        Date
        </th>
        <th class="heading"> 
        Process
        </th>
        <th class="heading"> 
        Curr Status
        </th>
        <th class="heading_blank"> 
        Change Status
        </th>
        <th class="heading_blank"> 

        </th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    include "config.php";
    $checkbox = isset($_POST['checked_box']);
    if($checkbox == 1){
        $Query="SELECT * FROM `order` ORDER BY sl_no DESC";
    }else{
        $Query="SELECT * FROM `order` ORDER BY sl_no ASC";    
    }
    $result=mysql_query($Query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) { 
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td class="content"> 
        <?php echo $row->sl_no; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="content"> 
        <?php echo $row->order_id; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="content"> 
        <?php echo $row->pick_date; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="content"> 
        <?php echo $row->process; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="content"> 
        <?php echo $row->status; ?>
        </td>
        <form action="update_status.php?order_id=<?php echo $row->order_id; ?>" method="POST">
                <td>
                <div class="select-style">              
                <select name="status">
                    <option value="<?php echo $row->status; ?>"><?php echo $row->status; ?></option>
                    <option value="Step_1">Step_1</option>
                    <option value="Step_2">Step_2</option>
                    <option value="Step_3">Step_3</option>
                    <option value="Step_4">Step_4</option>
                </select>
                </div>
                </td>
                <td> 
                <input type="submit" class="order_details_btn" value="Change">
                </td>
                </form>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

this page is came form this file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="script.js"></script><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getOrderStatus(value) {
                $.post("getOrderStatus.php", {partialOrderStatus:value},function(data){
                    $("#results").html(data);
                }
                ); 
            }
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function sortOrder() { 
            $.ajax( {
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'sortOrder.php',
                data: { checked_box : $('input:checkbox:checked').val()},

                success: function(data) {
                    $('#results').html(data);
                }
            } );
            }
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>


    <div id="floating-menu">

    <div id="order_tab">
                <div class="form_bg_alpha_order_status">

        <table id="order_hist">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:120px;">Search by:<input type="checkbox" name="checked_box" value="1" onclick="sortOrder()"></td>
            <td style="width:840px;"><input class="search" type="text" onkeyup="getOrderStatus(this.value)" placeholder="Order Id"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="results">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th class="heading"> 
                Sl No.
                </th>
                <th class="heading"> 
                Order Id
                </th>
                <th class="heading"> 
                Date
                </th>
                <th class="heading"> 
                Process
                </th>
                <th class="heading"> 
                Curr Status
                </th>
                <th class="heading_blank"> 
                Change Status
                </th>
                <th class="heading_blank"> 

                </th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            include "config.php";
            $result=mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE process='active'");
            while(($row= mysql_fetch_object ($result))!=null) {
            ?>

            <tr>
                <td class="content"> 
                <?php echo $row->sl_no; ?>
                </td>
                <td class="content"> 
                <?php echo $row->order_id; ?>
                </td>
                <td class="content"> 
                <?php echo $row->pick_date; ?>
                </td>
                <td class="content"> 
                <?php echo $row->process; ?>
                </td>
                <td class="content"> 
                <?php echo $row->status; ?>
                </td>
                <form action="update_status.php?order_id=<?php echo $row->order_id; ?>" method="POST">
                <td>
                <div class="select-style">              
                <select name="status">
                    <option value="<?php echo $row->status; ?>"><?php echo $row->status; ?></option>
                    <option value="Step_1">Step_1</option>
                    <option value="Step_2">Step_2</option>
                    <option value="Step_3">Step_3</option>
                    <option value="Step_4">Step_4</option>
                </select>
                </div>
                </td>
                <td> 
                <input type="submit" class="order_details_btn" value="Change">
                </td>
                </form>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            </table>
        </div>
        <body>
</html>
```

Here the submit form is work properly but is doesn't in the prev page

Comment: *doesn't work* is not helpful at all. Check the console and see if any errors have occurred.

Comment: `isset($_POST['checked_box']);` where  is your checkbox??

Comment: There's a reasonable chance that it's not working because `<form>` and `</form>` parts are in sections of HTML where they aren't valid.  Forms shouldn't be opened within tables where possible, and certainly shouldn't be opened between cells.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the invalid HTML, the form does submit and generate the alert in at least two browsers. Fix the HTML so that the forms are inside the TD elements and retest:

```
            <td>
            <form action="update_status.php?order_id=<?php echo $row->order_id; ?>" method="POST">
            <div class="select-style"  style="float: left; margin-right: 10px">              
            <select name="status">
                <option value="<?php echo $row->status; ?>"><?php echo $row->status; ?></option>
                <option value="Step_1">Step_1</option>
                <option value="Step_2">Step_2</option>
                <option value="Step_3">Step_3</option>
                <option value="Step_4">Step_4</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="order_details_btn" value="Change">
            </form>
            </td>
```

See [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) on how to view the console in different browers and add any errors reported to your question if required.

Comment: The code in your answer also contains invalid HTML where the `<form></form>` tags straddle two `td` containers.